# GCloud compute snapshots list doesn't show creation type

Tags: gcloud, gcp

Trying to sort out the GCP disk snapshots i have, and filter which snapshots had made by policy or backup software like veeam, or these snapshots made manualy by persone.
While in the console i can see the value of "creation type" for a snapshot, in cli i can't find this attribute.
I tried defferent formats but they al providing the same attributes, and there is no attribute for creation type.

the cli command:

```
gcloud compute snapshots list --format json
```